Exception: サービスがタイムアウトしました: スプレッドシート
gas実行中に上記のエラーが出て実行が止まってしまいます。
gas自体のタイムアウト（6分,30分）のものとは別のようです。
gasのタイムアウトの場合、実行ログに「タイムアウト」と表示されますが、このエラーの場合「失敗」と表示されます。
このようなエラーは検索しても出てこないのですが、同じような現象に遭遇した方はいますでしょうか。
ちなみに関数自体に問題はなく、同じデータ量でも完了まで行くときもあります。
環境としてはスプレッドシートのコンテナで作成しているスクリプトになります。
以下追加しました。
AppScriptの実行数ログに表示されるログは以下の通りです。
Exception: サービスがタイムアウトしました: スプレッドシート
Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets

どちらも同じ種類のエラーだと思いますが、なぜ日本語の場合と英語の場合で出力されるのかはよくわかりません。
出現する箇所も特定の部分に限らないのでソースは掲載してもあまり意味は無いように思っています。
少し考えてみて、言葉通りに捉えるとすると、AppScriptからスプレッドシートにアクセスするときにタイムアウトしているのではないかと思いました。
その場合、スクリプトの先頭の方で以下のようにシートへのアクセスするのでここで毎回タイムアウトするというのであれば納得いきますが、この部分でエラーが出ることは一度もありませんでした。
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);


どのようなコードを実行しているのか、ログに出力される詳細なメッセージを記載いただくと回答がつきやすくなると思います。

https://stackoverflow.com/q/64535334/7949528 この辺りに記載されていることは参考にならないでしょうか？

提示していただいたサイト非常に参考になりました、大変ありがとうございます！
＞シート内でデータに基づいて動作する数式や関数を多数実行している場合、これによ＞ってシートがオーバーロードされることもあります。データセットを更新するときに＞数式が動作しないようにフラグを設定します。私の場合はこれでうまくいきました。
この可能性が高そうです。
スプレッドシート側で関数や入力規則を多用しているのでそのへんが悪さをしているんじゃないかと推測しました。
